# Cuando el traductor añade palabras...

Tags: traducción, sintaxis

Me gustaría saber la opinión de traductores... Aquí tengo dos oraciones subordinadas finales:

> (a) Lo hacía a propósito **para que ella lo escuchara**.
>
> (b) Dio un paso hacia adelante **para que ella entrara**.

El traductor inglés y alemán añadieron un verbo modal: *so that she **could** hear him / so that she **could** come in*. Me pregunto por qué lo hicieron. Las oraciones son *para que ella lo escuchara / para que ella entrara* y no *para que ella **pudiera** entrar*. ¿Es normal?

Comment: Estás consultando si una traducción del castellano al inglés o alemán es correcta. No creo que esto sea [on topic](/help/on-topic) en este sitio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pregunta sobre traducciones a otros idiomas distintos del español.

Comment: Podrías intentar darle la vuelta a la pregunta, que es como la veo yo: si en inglés la traducción necesita un **could**, ¿por qué en español podemos decir simplemente "entrara" en vez de "pudiera entrar"? O "escuchara" en vez de "pudiera escuchar".

Comment: Me parece equivocado el uso de "**could**" en las oraciones que señala @Aurora, yo usaría "**would**"; el verbo escuchar a diferencia del verbo oír requiere intención por parte del sujeto o actor.  Opino igual en relación con el verbo entrar.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for German but in English I think the translator is right. The Spanish is using the conditional and both the versions you quote seem perfectly idiomatic English to me.